MySQL Java Call: How to solve MySQL syntax error with prepared statement, placeholder not updating correctly
I am new to Java and am trying to connect to a MySql DB, pull a total value from one of the tables, and then display that in the Application I'm building. However, I keep getting the following error:
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '?' at line 1
Is it because the "relationship" variable is returning null so the placeholder isn't being replaced? I have highlighted the line that is giving me errors. Please let me know if anyone has any insight.
try {
            
            Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/suspiciontokens?useSSL=false",
                    "chrislayton97","Rainforest_2011");
            
            String sqlpull = "SELECT TotalTokens FROM suspiciontokenstotals WHERE Relationship = ? ";
            PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement(sqlpull);
            ps.setString(1, relationship);
            ResultSet r = ps.executeQuery(sqlpull);
            
            
            if (r.next()) {
                Integer totalSusTokens = r.getInt("TotalTokens");
                totalResultLabel.setText("Total Suspicion Tokens: " + totalSusTokens);
            }
            
            con.close();
        }
        catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        
    }   

I have tried updating the executeQuery statement, I have tried using a hardcoded value and that does work for the values without an apostrophe in the relationship name but I don't want to do that to avoid SQL Injection.

ps.executeQuery(sqlpull); executes the raw query, not the prepared one. The docs dont even mention that method, does it exist? Use the one without the parameter.

ResultSet r = ps.executeQuery(); is what you want. You can lose the space after ? too

IOW ps.executeQuery(sqlpull) should be ps.executeQuery().

Get used to using try-with-resources too: final String sqlpull = "SELECT TotalTokens FROM suspiciontokenstotals WHERE Relationship = ?";try (Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/suspiciontokens?useSSL=false","chrislayton97", "Rainforest_2011");PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement(sqlpull)) {ps.setString(1, relationship);try (ResultSet r = ps.executeQuery(sqlpull)) {if (r.next()) {Integer totalSusTokens = r.getInt("TotalTokens");totalResultLabel.setText("Total Suspicion Tokens: " + totalSusTokens);}}} catch (SQLException e) {e.printStackTrace();}

You are calling executeQuery incorrectly.  Just call executeQuery(), do not pass in the sql string variable you have already prepared the query statement.
try {
        
        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/suspiciontokens?useSSL=false",
                "chrislayton97","Rainforest_2011");
        
        String sqlpull = "SELECT TotalTokens FROM suspiciontokenstotals WHERE Relationship = ?";
        PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement(sqlpull);
        ps.setString(1, relationship);
        ResultSet r = ps.executeQuery();
        
        
        if (r.next()) {
            Integer totalSusTokens = r.getInt("TotalTokens");
            totalResultLabel.setText("Total Suspicion Tokens: " + totalSusTokens);
        }
        
        con.close();
    }
    catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    
}  


… and use try-with-resources syntax to automatically close.
